# How to float an image and center headlines in remain space?

Tags: html, css, sass, alignment, flexbox

I want this structure, a container that has flex:display, an image floating on the right, then a h1 and h2, I want to put these vertical and horizontal center on the remaining space of the div.

This is my current result.

[image]

Mockup.

```
+-----------------------+
|                       |
|XXXX                   |
|XXXX     HELLFISH      |
|XXXX    born to die    |
|XXXX                   |
|                       |
+-----------------------+
```

This is the html code.

```
div.container
  img(src='http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/a/a1/Flying_Hellfish_Logo.png/revision/latest?cb=20150327234211')
  h1 HELLFISH
  h2 Born to die
```

The SCSS.

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  justify-content: space-between;
  img{
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    float: left;
  }
  h1{
    align-self: center;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  h2{
    align-self: center;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position: relative;
  }  
 }
```

The codepen.
http://codepen.io/TabaresSotelo/pen/pRyxPz

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Wrap the `h1` and `h2` in one container (which becomes a sibling flex item of the image).
- Use the `order` property to shift the image to the right.
- You don't need to use the `float` property or `justify-content: space-between`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.nested-container {
  flex: 1; /* to consume all remaining space */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container img {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  order: 1;
}
h1, h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/a/a1/Flying_Hellfish_Logo.png/revision/latest?cb=20150327234211" />
  <div class="nested-container">
    <h1>HELLFISH</h1>
    <h2>Born to die</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNqMYE) (compiled code)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap heading elements in another `div` and set `margin: 0 auto` on that div element. [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgGQav)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-items: center;
  img {
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
  }
  div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  h1,
  h2 {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
.container
  img(src='http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/a/a1/Flying_Hellfish_Logo.png/revision/latest?cb=20150327234211')
  div
    h1 HELLFISH
    h2 Born to die
```